# Location of dictionaries available for download

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

Where are the dictionaries for use in IBM Watson Knowledge Studio available for download located?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no place that the users share dictionaries for use in IBM Watson Knowledge Studio. At least IBM does not publish domain-specific dictionaries unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the built in dictionaries then these can't be downloaded as @sgnk mentions.

For user dictionaries it depends on how they are created. You can find dictionaries based on the following screen shot.

[image]

#### Option (1)

If you create a dictionary with the button it allows you to upload/download your dictionary.

### Option (2)

Selecting this option will create a read only dictionary (like department in the picture). You cannot download this dictionary once you have uploaded it. Nor can you change it.

### Option (3)

Download dictionary option will mass download all your editable dictionaries. Clicking it in the picture will download "Product Codes", "Locations" and their schema to a zip file.

---

Dictionaries in this instance are just CSV files with:

```
"lemma","poscode","surface"
```

`lemma` is the main word. 
`poscode` is the parts of speech code. 
`surface` is the variations of that term.

More information here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/knowledge-studio/dictionaries.html#dictionaries

---

For the dictionaries you create, either by rules or machine learning you can find in the "Versions" menu option under the related model you created.

There is a button there to download the model. If it's a PEAR or CAS file you can probably use it in UIMA, but I don't believe it is supported outside of Watson Explorer.

Comment: Thank you, Simon.  Admittedly, I am a novice at this.  So, there's not a standard dictionary that can be/is used by most folks for natural language processing?

Comment: The standard one is built into NLU. There is none you can download

Comment: Thank you, Simon!